# enable uart2, but reading from it is not right

Tags: linux, embedded, uart

I have a Ti processor AM335x on a dev board. right not there are two uart connect to processor. uart0 and uart2

by default, only uart0 was enable, and it was for console. after I enable uart2, I wired my GPS to it so that it should output something if I cat /dev/ttyO2.  but there are only some garbage code shows up.

then I wired GPS to uart0, use same command cat /dev/ttyO0  everything works fine. GPS output shows up normally.

then I edit my uEnv.txt to switch my console to uart2, it works. and then I wired GPS to uart2, I can cat /dev/ttyO2 to get everything. But when I wired GPS to uart0. garbage code shows up.

I did use stty to do tty setup, make them all same, still, I can only read from the uart which I connect my console.

I run command dmesg | grep tty  , this is the output

```
    [0.000000] Kernel command line: console=ttyO2,115200n8 root=/dev/mmcblk0 rw ext4 rootwait verbose debug
    [0.234749] 44e09000.serial: ttyO0 at MMIO 0x44e09000 (irq = 154m, base_baud = 3000000) is a OMAP UART0
    [0.235338] 48024000.serial: ttyO2 at MMIO 0x48024000 (irq = 155m, base_baud = 3000000) is a OMAP UART2   
    [0.824084] console [ttyO2] enabled
```

first and fourth would change base on which uart I put my console on.
Are there any config I missed? why I can only read precise data from the uart I put my console on. and others doesn't work.

any idea would help. Thanks.

This is how I change my code to enable uart2. 
[linux compile for enable uart2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39780105/linux-compile-for-enable-uart2)

Comment: At absolute minimum, set the baudrate. I think there's a tool *stty* to do that, but you should probably use some special purpose utility that deals with serial ports, like minicom.

Comment: @domen  I did try stty, but still cannot read. I might try minicom, but I don't think it's will work.

Comment: Did you set the **BAUDRATE**? What is GPS's baudrate, and what's ttyO0/2 set to?

Comment: This is just for gibberish part, you might still need to match flow control settings, number of bits, parity bit etc. 8 bits, no parity, 1 stop bit, no flow control is something reasonable to try.

Comment: @domen I did, that's the first thing I check. I use stty -F /dev/ttyO2 115200 to set the tty baudrate.  am I correct?  I will double make sure that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that is BAUDRATE problem.

not because I didn't setup right, is because a hardware problem. as soon as I connect my GPS to uart2. the uart2 baudrate would change to 9600 and that gives me garbage output.

if I stty setup the baudrate to 115200 and start read. THEN connect my GPS. I get everything I need with correct format.

Still don't know what issue with GPS, but that's shouldn't be part of this question. so I will close this.

Thank you, @domen  without you I won't double check that baudrate.